# How to find the trace and determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $A$ has eigenvalues $1, 2, 4$
What is the trace of $A^{2}$?

Since trace of $A$ is $1+2+4=7$, that of $A^{2}$ is $7\times7=49$? Or am I missing something?

What is the determinant of $(A^{-1})^{T}$?

$det(A)=1\times 2\times 4=8$ and I know that $(A^{-1})^{T}$ = $(A^{T})^{-1}$. Since eigenvalues are on the diagonal, $det(A^{T}) = det(A) = 8$ now I'm kind of stuck. Do I just take the inverse of 8? So the $det(A^{-1})^{T}=\frac{1}{8}$?

Comment: To see why the $49$ is not correct, try doing this with a diagonal matrix.

Comment: To find the trace of $A^2$, you are right about using a square operation on the eigenvalues of $A$. However as @Tobias has rightly pointed out, your result is incorrect. In which order should you apply the squaring operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Notice that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$, in fact if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated to $\lambda$ then
$$A^2 x=A(Ax)=\lambda Ax=\lambda^2 x$$
 For the determinant we use two facts:
$$\det A=\det(A^T)$$
and if $\lambda\ne0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\frac 1\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. What about the determinant of $(A^{-1})^{T}$? Did I approach it correctly?

Comment: I edited my answer@Adrian